# Bash substring test detecting empty string as a substring of a non-empty string

Tags: bash

Consider this...

```
#!/bin/bash
declare STR='test'
declare SUB=''
[[ "${STR}" == *"${SUB}"* ]] && echo 'match'
```

This appears to resolve or evaluate to true?  This makes no sense to me.

To get the expected result you have to test if the SUB string is empty?

```
#!/bin/bash
declare STR='test'
declare SUB=''
[[ ! -z "${SUB}" ]] && [[ "${STR}" == *"${SUB}"* ]] && echo 'match'
```

Is this some quirk with BASH or such?  If the sub string is NOT in the string should it not return false?

Comment: Why's it odd? The empty substring, by nature, exists everywhere: it's before, after, and between each character of any string you like. Why would `[[ foo = * ]]` be different from `[[ foo = *'' ]]` or `[[ foo = *''* ]]` or `[[ foo = ''* ]]`?

Comment: I've never known any language to exist that _doesn't_ behave this way. Compare to Python: `'' in 'foo'` is true. So is `'foo'.endswith('')`, and `'foo'.startswith('')`.

Comment: The empty string doesn't exist as a distinct thing to match. `*"${SUB}"*` is exactly identical to `**`, which is semantically the same as `*` (although with multiple different ways to match).

Comment: `*"${SUB}"*` Why did you put asterisks?  `[[ 'whatever' == * ]]` will always match! Not an odd behavior at all... when `SUB=''` is left blank it will match, when `SUB='foo'` has "some other" value it will NOT match.

Comment: @dachshund-digital, ...for example, see https://ideone.com/X9jyaj showing the same behavior (detecting a match at the very first character) for C's `strstr()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should explicitly check for a possible empty string, but I'd use `-n` instead of a *not*, and in `bash` you can make it a single compound condition check.

```
$: x=abcdefg
$: y=cde
$: [[ -n "$y" && "$x" =~ $y ]] && echo match || echo no
match
$: y=
$: [[ -n "$y" && "$x" =~ $y ]] && echo match || echo no
no
```

...and you don't need the leading and trailing globs, they don't really add anything.

Answer (score 1):

The empty string is part of *every* string. Thus, testing whether an empty string is a substring of anything else is always true.

---

This is not specific to bash or in any way unusual; you can check it in other languages.

- Python: `print('' in 'foo')` prints `True`.
- Java: `String("foo").contains("")` returns true.
- C: `strstr("foo", "")` returns a pointer to the first character in `foo`, meaning it found a match.
- Ruby: `"foo".include? ""` returns true.